# auto_ptr to normal pointer conversion

Tags: c++, pointers, auto-ptr

Are we able to convert a std::auto_ptr to a normal pointer??

```
    class Test
    {
     ......
    }

    Test* function()
    {
      std::auto_ptr<Test> test(new Test());

      return _____//TODO : need to convert this auto_ptr to Test*
    }
```

Is it possible to convert an auto_ptr pointer which is created locally to normal pointer.

Comment: BTW, `std::auto_ptr` is now deprecated in favor of `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable suggestions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [release()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/auto_ptr/release/)

```
Test* function()
{
  std::auto_ptr<Test> test(new Test());

  return test.release()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to convert an auto_ptr pointer which is created locally to normal pointer.

Yes:

```
return test.release();
```

Answer (score 1):

See release method of std::auto_ptr: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/auto_ptr/release/